# Parameterized logging from Jboss to AWS cloud Watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jboss7.x, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an application on spring boot which is running on JBoss EAP 7.2 server and the application is deployed as a WAR file, all my applications logs are getting to the server.log and when I check the cloud watch logs its just printing the STDOUT's and not the one which is parameterized (log.debug or log.info). My application server is in the ECS container and I am really missing out on the connection between the Jboss server.log to AWS. Can someone help me out with this All my parameterized logs (log.debug) must be printed in the AWS cloud watch? Are there any third-party tools or there are configs changes which are needed to be made?

```
    This is how my logging Subsystem looks like                                                        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parameterized logs"? Are you getting no logs to `stdout`?

Comment: Parameterized logs in the sense which is in the log.debug ,all my stdouts are printing and getting to the cloud watch but not the ones which are parametrized(log.debug or log.info ).

Comment: I apologize I still don't understand. Do you mean if you did something like `log.debug("My debug message")` you're not seeing "My default message" in your cloud watch logs?

Comment: Yes ,Exactly you got that right .When i give stdout("My message ") its getting to the cloud watch logs but when I give log.debug("My debug message") I am not seeing "My default message".

Comment: What does the logging subsystem configuration look like? Do you have a `console-handler` defined?

Comment: I have added the logging subsystem config in he post @JamesR.Perkins.

Comment: To see debug messages you'd need to change the log level on the console-handler. `/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name="level", value="DEBUG")`.

Comment: Even the log.info("welcome") is not getting to the cloud watch .Whichever is parameterized (log.info ,log.debug,etc) is not getting to the cloudwatch but whatever is given in the sdtout is getting to the cloud watch@JamesR.Perkins .

Comment: I don't know anything about cloud watch, but maybe it's being discarded. You could try switching to the `named-formatter` from `COLOR-PATTERN` to `PATTERN`. Maybe it doesn't like the color codes.

Answer (score 0):

Your root logger having default level as INFO, which will filter out your debug level log messages to STDOUT, and I believe you have a code to stream all STDOUT to cloud watch, so that's why if you put your message directly to STDOUT it works